# Launch an MvxActivity from a NuGet package

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I try to launch an `MvxActivity` located in a NuGet package which also contains the `ViewModel`.

From my application, I can use `ShowViewModel()` function to call the ViewModel` in the NuGet package like so:

```
(ShowViewModel<packageB.ViewModels.MvxActivityInBViewModel>(‌​));
```

On the other hand, it seems that the view is not visible from my application. I have an error saying:

```
> KeyNotFoundException: Could not find view for
> packageB.ViewModels.MvxActivityInBViewModel
```

Code:

```
public ICommand GoToAppB
{
  get
  {
      return new MvxCommand(() => ShowViewModel<packageB.ViewModels.MvxActivityInBViewModel>());
  }
}
```

Any suggestions ? :/ Is it possible to do such a thing ?

Comment: What do you mean by "Don't know the MvxActivity"? Isn't the `ViewModelOfMvxActivityInB` inherited from `MvxActivity`?

Comment: "ViewModelOfMvxActivityInB" is the ViewModel associated with the MvxActivity i want to run.

Comment: Please re-read my previous question. Also, which "different package" are you trying to use? As it is right now, the question is too broad, which consequently means that it will be difficult to provide a good answer

Comment: Well, have you defined a view yourself for the ViewModel? Also, please update your question with the the stacktrace and consider adding the other things i asked for. It will make it easier for others to help you, as the details will be overlooked in the comments section.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear enough. Question updated :)

Comment: Which NuGet package are you referring to?

Comment: Do you mean you created a nuget package yourself and want to use the activity inside?

Comment: Yes indeed :) I just found the solution yesterday ! I can "package" a solution with ios library, android library and pcl and call the first ios/android activity from my main app.